# golang hangs when using multipart/form-data

Tags: go, telegram, multipartform-data, telegram-bot

I want to make an empty post request to telegram.
The problem is if i close multipart once, it hangs forever:

```
 func main() {
    var requestBody bytes.Buffer
    multiPartWriter := multipart.NewWriter(&requestBody)
    multiPartWriter.Close()      // closing once
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot<telegram token>/getme", &requestBody)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", multiPartWriter.FormDataContentType())
    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Do(req)
}
```

But if i close the multipart twice it works.
Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Hi, what exactly is your problem? 

Tested your snippet, it works.

https://play.golang.org/p/_SiH1s8rkQw

Comment: hi @TobiasTheel you need to change <telegram token> with a valid token to see the problem

Comment: I don't have any telegram tokens, so I cannot help unless you could provide a reproducible example

Comment: The response is: {"ok":true,"result":{"id":<censored>,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Test","username":"<censored>can_join_groups":true,"can_read_all_group_messages":false,"supports_inline_queries":false}}

Comment: Ah i found out how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the Telegram API.

I guess the general problem is, that you use a buffer that is not initialized.
You don't need the buffer, you don't need any payload in the request. You can just pass nil as request data. Like this:

```
func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getme", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    client := &http.Client{}

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    result, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    println(string(result))
}
```

I also recommend, that you check out the docs [here](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/reference/getme) this documentation lets you interactively try out the API, it can also generate the code for each request.

In order to generate Go code examples, you can click on the button at the upper right corner and chose your Go.

[image: screenshot of telegram api docs]